# Generating tokens with slim-jwt-auth

Tags: php, jwt, slim-3

I'm using [slim-jwt-auth](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/slim-jwt-auth) to create token based authentication for a JSON API.

The docs are very helpful, but one thing I don't understand is how are the tokens generated? The docs say that the middleware is able to decode the token, but can't see any way to encode.

Some projects I've seen use [firebase/jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt), but I'm not sure if this is needed, or compatible with `slim-jwt-auth`.

Is slim-jwt-auth able to generate tokens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can but you do not need to install extra libraries to generate the token. The middleware uses [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) internally so you can use the same library to generate the token. Something like the following.

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use \Tuupola\Base62;

$now = new DateTime();
$future = new DateTime("now +2 hours");
$jti = Base62::encode(random_bytes(16));

$secret = "your_secret_key";

$payload = [
    "jti" => $jti,
    "iat" => $now->getTimeStamp(),
    "nbf" => $future->getTimeStamp()
];

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $secret, "HS256");
```

You might also check the [Slim API Skeleton](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-api-skeleton/) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

According to the disclaimer on the [`slim-jwt-auth`](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/slim-jwt-auth) landing page the middleware only processes tokens; does not provide any way to generate them.

> HEADS UP! Middleware does not implement OAuth 2.0 authorization server **nor does it provide ways to generate, issue or store authentication tokens**. It only parses and authenticates a token when passed via header or cookie.

<sub>(emphasis is mine)</sub>

You can indeed use another library to generate JWT tokens which will then be consumed by `slim-jwt-auth`. As long as both libraries implemented the specification correctly you should have no interoperability problems at least if you only use the mandatory to implement parts of the specification.

---

You can check [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) for a list of PHP libraries for JWT processing, but `firebase/jwt` would be a good starting point. If instead of generating the tokens yourself you're looking into completely delegate the authentication and issuance of tokens to a third-party, then I would suggest having a look at [Auth0](https://auth0.com/).

<sub>**Disclosure**: I work at Auth0.</sub>